# Upgraded Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 21.10 but a few days after only black screen after boot

Tags: boot, 20.04, 21.10

as the title mentions. I had a stable Ubuntu 20.04 version. I don't know why... but i upgraded to 21.10. So far it has been horrible.

BIG EDIT: After trying to write something on my m.2 with cp it said that it is only in read mode and not write mode. What does that mean?

After trying to relogg from windows (Another partition) into my Ubuntu, it just failed. After a few restarts i found out that it is sometimes working and sometimes not. I started to panic and found out that i might have to run fsck which i did run with the -all flag and the -p and the -f flag several times.

My partion is lvma encrypted and it had 3 partitions under the main /dev/nvme disk. I tried them all with fsck, on one of them it said something about a nasty bit, i pressed yes, then it asked me if i want to safe the changes or not, i typed no to not do any mistake. After rebooting i realized that i am completely locked out of the system.

After typing my password to decrypt the partition the boot would fail.

The error messages were different each time. Sometimes i was having the message that snapd couldn't load service, or ' PCIe Bus error: Severity-Uncorrected(non-fatal) type Transaction layer,

Other times it was a SQUASHFS error failed to read block 0xsomethin -5
in combination with FAT-fs directory bread block failed.

I am now on me 9th day trying to figure out what might have gone wrong, but it seems like i can't figure it out. I tried to run an older kernel but it didn't work either.

If i run recovery mode and then run all the things inside of it with the final one being proceed to normal boot, it does boot, otherwise it won't. Why?

Comment: Are you using an installed system?  Ubuntu has two intended *release-upgrade* paths, via every release (ie. 20.04 -> 20.10 -> 21.04 -> 21.10 -> 22.04) OR from one LTS release to the next (ie. 20.04 -> 22.04.1) so for best results you should use one of those paths.  You also mention *squashfs* errors which imply media errors as is common on uninstalled systems running from *live* media? though you can also have *squashfs* on an installed system; it still refers to media errors (check the drive it's on).  Your question though is unclear as you don't have command & exact error messages

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/06/18/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades   *You've tagged an EOL & thus off-topic release?  It was likely not what you mean (it's an upgrade your system missed in your description) but you should correct your question*

Comment: @guiverc yes i am using an installed system. So a question about the drive. I edited my post. After trying to write something on my m.2 with cp it said that it is only in read mode and not write mode. What does that mean?

It's not 20.10 it's 21.10

Comment: You've tagged 20.10 as your release; look at your post (tagging two releases which makes no sense as you can only be running one release at a time).  You tagged 20.04 & 20.10; 20.10 is EOL & thus off-topic thus my comment. Correct your post and I'll delete my comment.